# Как на Apache с PHP 7 запустить версию PHP 5.3

Tags: php, apache

Есть локальный сервер на Apache с PHP версии 7 но в списке сайтов есть некоторые написаные с версией 5.3 и из за того что некоторый функционал не работает в особенности mysql_connect и все подобные без PDO с этими сайтами невозможно работать как то можно сделать чтобы работало с прежними версиями без отката всего веб сервера?

Comment: А зачем использовать `mysql`? Пора забыть про него, в новых версиях его давным-давно удалили. используйте `mysqli` или `PDO` и проблемы отпадут сами собой.

Comment: @And, видимо речь идёт о старых проектах.

Comment: да) речь о старых проектах как раз

Comment: @Streletz. В чем проблема старых проектов? В том, что у них везде и всюду написано подключение и т. д. копипаст? Использование не рекомендуемых функций, которые помечены устаревшими? И файлов тьма? Нет никакой логики? Или в чем проблема то? - `раз написано на оф.-сайте-лучше не использовать (то лучше не использовать).`

Comment: @And, архитектурных и не только антипаттернов и во многих новых проектах навалом. Просто любое ПО не существует само по себе. Оно решает задачи внутреннего или внешнего заказчика.Если система ответственная, то заказчик начинает относиться как в анекдоте: "Каждый день работает? — Да, каждый день.
— Тогда ничего не трогай, ничего не меняй". А, в остальном я с Вами согласен.

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно к этому Апачу вы уже не прикрутите параллельно php другой версии в качестве модуля Апача.

Единственный вариант, который я вижу, это использовать php-as-cgi для сайтов, которым нужна старая версия php. Т.е. надо будет установить на сервер php 5.3 (не сломав при этом 7-ю версию), потом переконфигурить виртуалхосты (которым нужна версия 5.3), чтобы php для них был в качестве cgi.

Comment: а какой нибудь ини не существует чтобы быстро и просто?

Comment: @misha11 не понял вопрос. Какой-нибудь `ини` - что имеется ввиду?

Comment: ну ini команды которые обычно испоьзуются для изменния конфигрурации например для большей выделяемой памяти и т п

Answer (score 0):

В качестве одного из возможных вариантов.
Разместить нужную версию PHP в `cgi-bin`, и направить на неё `Apache` при помощи `.htaccess`.

```
AddHandler php-cgi .php .htm Action php-cgi /cgi-bin/php5.cgi
```

ИМХО, и быстро и просто.